# How to attach current url link to COPY THS TEXT for this code?

Tags: jquery

I have a button that will copy "COPY THS TEXT" to clipboard using the jquery.

i want to make the "COPY THS TEXT" link to current URL

```
<button class="js-copy-bob-btn">Set clipboard to BOB</button><br />

function fallbackCopyTextToClipboard(text) {
  var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
  textArea.value = text;
  document.body.appendChild(textArea);
  textArea.focus();
  textArea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Fallback: Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Fallback: Oops, unable to copy', err);
  }

  document.body.removeChild(textArea); 
}
function copyTextToClipboard(text) {
  if (!navigator.clipboard) {
    fallbackCopyTextToClipboard(text);
    return;
  }
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(function() {
    console.log('Async: Copying to clipboard was successful!');
  }, function(err) {
    console.error('Async: Could not copy text: ', err);
  });
}

var copyBobBtn = document.querySelector('.js-copy-bob-btn');

copyBobBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
  copyTextToClipboard('COPY THS TEXT');
});
```

id like the COPY THS TEXT to be linked to the current page so it would be

`<a href="THIS IS THE CURRENT PAGE HERE VIA JQUERY">COPY THS TEXT</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this...
Here is the function where you need to add some lines.

```
    <button class="js-copy-bob-btn">Set clipboard to BOB</button><br />
<script type="text/javascript">
function fallbackCopyTextToClipboard(text) {
  var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
  textArea.value = text;
  document.body.appendChild(textArea);
  textArea.focus();
  textArea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Fallback: Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Fallback: Oops, unable to copy', err);
  }

  document.body.removeChild(textArea); 
}
function copyTextToClipboard(text) {
  if (!navigator.clipboard) {
    fallbackCopyTextToClipboard(text);
    return;
  }
  var currentURL = window.location.href;
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(currentURL+text).then(function() {
    console.log('Async: Copying to clipboard was successful!');
  }, function(err) {
    console.error('Async: Could not copy text: ', err);
  });
}

var copyBobBtn = document.querySelector('.js-copy-bob-btn');

copyBobBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
  copyTextToClipboard('COPY THS TEXT');
});
</script>
```

Comment: cant seem to get that working. still just copies "COPY THIS TEXT"